# Error while running Calendar project

Tags: android

I have downloaded calendar project from https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar and now I'm trying to run that project. I imported the project to eclipse via `new --> Android project from existing source`, it imported successfully but I'm getting a red exclamation mark in project, like this:

[image]

When I went to `properties > Android` I'm seeing this:

[image]

It looks like the project is using some libraries but is not able to find in the workspace. How can I fix this?

Comment: This looks like your external library is using other libraries. You will need to import them to get it to work.

Comment: @PhilippJahoda where I will get `..\..\..\framework\ex\chips`?

Comment: @JackDaniels did you can download libraries?

Comment: Did you solved this problem ?

Comment: Did anyone try to open it in the android studio? How to make it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may to add the following dependencies as well.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ex/

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/colorpicker/

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/calendar/

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/datetimepicker/

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/timezonepicker/

Comment: How can I download these sources?

Comment: You can clone the repos . for example `git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ex` . But what I am afraid is that you may need other dependencies for that as well. However, you gotta try first :)

Comment: @JackDaniels please help me. I also getting same this... How to download these... please mail me kcmajestic@ymail.com

Comment: @OneManArmy you can `git clone` the above repos yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

remove all the library from here and import each and every one in your project workspace and then after add the library.

Comment: From where to import these?