# Source code for new Android Lollipop Calendar app

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-calendar

Does anyone know where I can find the source code for the updated Android Calendar app that is present in 5.0?

I did look at this where the [source for the old Calendar app](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar) is present but I did not find where the viewpager for the months is present. In fact I did not even find the new calendar launcher. So I feel like I might be looking for it in the wrong place.

Here is the screen in particular that I am looking for. I want to see how Google did that paging across months, highlighted the selected day, days with events and also how they are resizing the view pager when there are lesser weeks in months.

[image: The Month Calendar is at the top and is swipable.]

Comment: It isn't open source.

Comment: I was hoping it is especially since all the old android Calendar code is available. I already started building and got the months working but have at least a few days of work before I get it anywhere close. Not to mention maintenance :)

Comment: @archie have you found how to get latest calendar source code?

Answer (score 10):

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git/+/android-5.1.0_r3) is the source for 5.1 revision 3.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git/+archive/android-5.1.0_r3.tar.gz

Comment: thanks .i have download it but not able to run code it will give morethan100 errors

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629889/error-while-running-calendar-project .....   i would try to get it working myself when i get time  :)

Comment: hi, Thanks for this answer.
I downloaded the source code and build it.
But i am unable the code related to "Schedule" option in the calendar which is shown in the above screen shot.
Please help me if you have any updates regarding the above screen look.

Comment: It's the old version. Check the icons there.

Comment: @ArtemNovikov , How clone the newer version because I was able to run only the older version, have to managed to clone it? :/

Comment: @Raj How clone the newer version because I was able to run only the older version, have to managed to clone it? :/