# Developing Custom calendar with month/week/day views and adding events to it

Tags: android, events, calendar

I need to develop an application in which we have a calendar with month, week, day views, the user can add events to the views, but i don't know how do i take start, if any one have idea of implementing calendar, with such requirements plz help me out. any step by step tutorials or project source code will be appreciated.i have tried https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calendar project from github but got errors in it,
[image]

i have visited some questions at stackoverflow [Error while running Calendar project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629889/error-while-running-calendar-project) 
which tells to remove the error in github's project but have. but they need to clone some links i have not experience of taking clone from the link https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ex/ 
in simple i can not find the libraries which are shown in image.
 please guide me to develop such app in which we have month/week/day view and we can add events also. thanx.

Comment: Hello, DId you able to solve this? I am looking for the solution for Monthview. Check Please http://stackoverflow.com/q/39031661/819135