# Deploying Google Calendar project gives INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, android-calendar

I have been  able to clone and build Google Calendar app along with its dependencies, thanks to this post : [Error while running Calendar project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629889/error-while-running-calendar-project)

But i am unable to get it to run on Emulator or Tablet (Galaxy Tab 4), apparently it is trying to overwrite and an existing app and i'm getting the  `Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE`
On Emulator i tried a manual delete of the app Calendar:

`rm -rf /system/apps/Calendar/Calendar.apk` and  `rm -rf /data/data/com.android.calendar`

On Tablet i tried the same thing, plus a google app `GoogleCalendarSyncAdapter.apk`

`rm -rf /system/apps/GoogleCalendarSyncAdapter.apk` and  `rm -rf /data/data/com.google.android.syncadapters.calendar`

But nothing helped, i'm still getting the same version downgrade error.

I also tried to force downgrade with `$adb install -r AppName.apk`but as expected i get an `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES`

Can someone please point to the app colliding with google calendar App, or what should i delete to be able to deploy. thanks in advance.

By the way the project is named `AllInOneActivity`the APK name is `AllInOneActivity.apk`

Comment: will you help me to solve this ? even adding all the dependencies also i am  getting the same error like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629889/error-while-running-calendar-project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change package name of your app - from com.android.calendar to something unique.

Comment: I feel stupid it didn't cross my mind. it worked, thank you.
However Changing package application name via Android tools resulted into a `INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED`. i had to change also the physical package names.