# Google Calendar - Android studio ex/chips

Tags: google-calendar-api

I am a little bit new to android studio.

I cloned the google calendar from git, and I tried to import it into android studio, but always the ex/chips not found. I found a response but I didn't achieve anything.

[the error I am having](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ceu4n.png)

Your help please ! 
thanks in advance !

Comment: Please provide some code...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while running Calendar project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629889/error-while-running-calendar-project)

Comment: Hamza were you able to successfully build the project? Can you help please?

Comment: @JamesBond No sir, I am sorry, I found that there is some dependencies on the Android project that I couldn't solve, so I abandoned this way.